# SVG.js group is returning exponential value although I'm storing it as a string in group

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg.js

Storing numeric value as String in group(some attribute) using SVG.js. How to get value as string instead of numeric exponential value.Although I'm converting value to String before adding to group. While re-fetching, group is giving exponential. How to avoid this?

Comment: Please give us some code to work with

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xr10mmd1/2/  please refer this link.

Comment: svg.js tries to guess if the attribute you wanna get is from type number. If so, it uses parseFloat to return a number to you. If you want to have back the string value of the number use `viewGroup.node.getAttribute('myVal')`

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem:)

Answer (score 0):

Copied over from my comment:

> svg.js tries to guess if the attribute you wanna get is from type number. If so, it uses `parseFloat` to return a number to you. If you want to have back the string value of the number use `viewGroup.node.getAttribute('myVal')`